# How to receive POST data of ajax call in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cordova, datatables

I need a little help. I am trying to implement bootstrap data table with ajax pagination. As this is mobile app (Cordova), I am fully dependent on javascript for server side too. Thats why in the url I am calling javascript function. Now I am not sure about how to get the POST data in it. Any help will be appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("‪#‎products‬").dataTable({
     aLengthMenu: [
       [10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]
     ],
     aaSorting: [],
     bProcessing: true,
     serverSide: true,
    ajax:{
      url : ProductList.getProductsPaginated(),
      type: "post", // type of method , by default would be get
      error: function(){ // error handling code
    }
  }
});

ProductList.getProductsPaginated(){
// This method gets called succesfully
// Need the post data here
}
});
```

Edit:
Let, without using the function as url param, let use a html page directly like

```
url : "page.html",
```

Now, how to get those post data in the html or js? Is there any other way for what I am looking?

Comment: Why do you need ajax to call a JS function?

Comment: I have said that already "I am fully dependent on javascript for server side too."  I am using datatable in a cordova based application. Mainly HTML and Javascript. I get the data from sqlite database using javascript. Hope you understand.

Comment: Ok I'm not even quire sure where to start with your question.  The `url` of your ajax request should be an actual url/address to an endpoint your node backend provides.  Your node server will do whatever processing/getting information you need and will respond.  This response will show up in a `success` or `error` function in your ajax request.  From there you can do whatever you want with it on the front end.  You aren't going to be accessing your SQLite database from your front end, unless I am sorely mistaken

Comment: I have mentioned that this is an mobile app, and I am gonna get data from sqlite db. For example, say, In getProductsPaginated() I will execute the select query  from the sqlite db. Hope you understand.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thank you all for trying to help me. I have found no way to post data to a javascript function using ajax. In this case, I am unable to use DataTable's ajax feature to minimise data loading time by pagination. Ajax call can be made to server-side scripts only. Thats why I have disabled datatable's paging and implemented custom pagination using javascript.

Comment: Whoever giving down vote, should left a comment about the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need the data inside that function, but it isn't getting called on ajax success, it's invoked because of the parenthesis, the only thing I think you could do there is to return the path of your json data, however you can call a function with your post data on ajax success like this:

```
ajax: {
 url : ProductList.getProductsPaginated(),
 type: "post",
 dataSrc: function (data) {
  // you can call a function here with the data as parameter
  // you have to return the data, with modifications if you need
  return data;
 }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is incorrect, see [`ajax`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax#object) option - *`success` - Must not be overridden as it is used internally in DataTables*.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that, edited as documentation suggests, thanks.